# How can I plot an array into a 2-d plot where y-axis is number of occurence of data in array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, plot

So I have an array of numbers, and I want to plot how many times each number occurs in the array. X-axis should be the numbers in the array, and y-axis should be the number of times each number occurs in the array. Is there a way to program this in python? Also I have trouble when I try to import numpy or matplotlib.pyplot, so is there a way I can do this?

Comment: It sounds like you want a [histogram](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
t = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8] #your original list of numbers
noDuplicates = list(set(t)) #gets rid of duplicates in your list

listOfTuples = []

for number in noDuplicates:
    count = t.count(number)
    newTuple = [number, count]
    listOfTuples.Append(newTuple)
```

This creates a list of tuples where the fist number of the tuple is the number you are trying to count and the second number is the count. this will work for the decimals that my first solution did not because i did not know that you needed it to work with decimals. with this list of tuples you should very easily be able to create your graph.

Comment: I don't completely understand the logic behind this. Could you explain?

Comment: What i am doing is creating a list of every single number that appears the original list of numbers without duplicates. Then i can loop through that list and for each unique number in the new list (it has no duplicates) i can see how many times that number appears in the original list (t.count(number)) where t is the original list and number is the number that we are trying to count. so for each unique value in our original list, we can get the exact number of appearances. Once we have that number we pair the count with the original number with a tuple to we can reference it later when needed

Comment: That depends on how you are wanting to display it and store it. What are you going to use to display it? I would suggest something like this: http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html  if you are having trouble importing it, i would google it because it is probably something that you need to download for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet would be to create a separate list to keep track of the number of occurrences in your first list where the number you are tracking is the index of the second list.

```
    listOfNumbers = [2,3,4,2,6,4,2]
    listOfOccurrences = range(x)   #x-1 is the largest number that should occur in the first list  
    for number in listOfNumbers:
         listOfOccurances[number] += 1
```

then if you want to know how many times a number appears in your original list, just use that number as the index for the second list and the value of that spot is the number that you are looking for. then you can make your 2d array where the x axis is your number then you can set the y axis as the number of occurrences.

Comment: The numbers in the array are only between 0.1 and 3.9 though, and they have up to 15 decimal places.